# django rest-auth/registration email validation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I have the following in my settings in the django rest framework app:

```
#settings.py
REST_USE_JWT = True
SITE_ID = 1
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mytestaccount@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mytestaccountPassword'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
```

with this settings I can sign up a new user and the following message pops up in console upon registration :

"""""From: mytestaccount@gmail.com
To: test3@gmail.com
Date: Sat, 05 Jan 2019 05:15:11 -0000
Message-ID: <154666531119.43600.12499673333763651759>

Hello from example.com!

You're receiving this e-mail because user amir3 has given yours as an e-mail address to connect their account.

To confirm this is correct, go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/OA:1gfeIh:QM0KigIvCJXX5otapkQccUMfbwk/

Thank you from example.com!
example.com""""""

my question is that how can I make it to actually email me rather than just printing in console. I tried the following setting instead:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

but what happens is that the user will be added to the database with no email sent, let alone verifying by clicking the link,

Would you please let me know what am I missing here,

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the same settings, and that works for me.

You need to allow "unsafe apps" on your gmail account though, this link will tell you how to do that:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: thanks it helped me to send out email, but the problem is that even though it sends a link for conformation it doesn't wait for confirming and it adds the user to database right away after filling up the required information upon registration.

Comment: It is normal that the user is already in the database before the validation link is clicked. The validation link is only to confirm that the email the user gave is correct. The Django rest auth FAQ has some more advice on how to handle the actual email validation (see point one), as the default link does not work. Link to FAQ: https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html

Comment: I have it worked based on your suggestion and comments here: https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/issues/292 , however this provide me with a GET request of the form  http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/MTY:1ggGpL:n8gHmRfOzgjR2vZTHopxiUkCe-w/ which is basically the link in the email that user is clicked and I receive it as GET request. Is this how I am supposed to verify the email?